# How to to add a new column that will count the number of duplicates value from a specific column

Tags: sql-server

I would like to add a new column that will count the number of duplicates value from a specific column and present the count outcome in the first occurrence row of the table.
For example, having the toy table below :

```
ID LOGIN NAME   COUNTRY
11 a@com  Aron  USA
12 a@com  Aron  Israel
13 ff@com Lucci Germany
```

I would like to get the count of LOGIN field in the first occurrence row of the table:

```
ID LOGIN NAME   COUNTRY Count_LOGIN
11 a@com  Aron  USA         2
12 a@com  Aron  Israel      
13 ff@com Lucci Germany     1
```

How can I do it?
I know that I can save the table as a temp and then do something like what is written below but it is not exactly what I need.

```
SELECT LOGIN , COUNT(*) TotalCount
FROM #tt -- #tt is the first table 
GROUP BY LOGIN 
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```

Comment: Question: Why does Israel not have a value for `Count_LOGIN`?

Comment: That's because the login field is the important one and I would like to see the rows count by LOGIN and present this value only on the first row .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you can use `ALTER TABLE` to add the new column `Count_LOGIN`.  Then, use an `UPDATE` statement with a subquery to populate that column.  The query in your question looks spot on for what you want.

```
ALTER TABLE #tt
ADD Count_LOGIN int;

UPDATE #tt
SET Count_LOGIN =
(
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM #tt b
    WHERE #tt.LOGIN = b.LOGIN
    GROUP BY LOGIN
)
```

**Update:**

Assuming you only want to update the record for each `LOGIN` group which has the smallest `ID` value, you can try the following join `UPDATE` query:

```
UPDATE #tt
SET #tt.Count_LOGIN = t.TotalCount
FROM #tt
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT LOGIN, MIN(ID) AS ID, COUNT(*) AS TotalCount
    FROM #tt
    GROUP BY LOGIN
) t
    ON #tt.ID = t.ID AND #tt.LOGIN = t.LOGIN
```

This query will only affect records from your original `#tt` table which match the minimum `ID` value for each `LOGIN` group.  This would leave the other records in that group without a value.

Comment: May want to add AND TotalCount>=1, looks like the update should not happen when count is 0 as per the example above.

Comment: Thanks @Tim Biegeleisen ,  I get an error of  Invalid column name 'Count_LOGIN'

Comment: @mql4beginner Sorry for the syntax error, I have updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks @Tim Biegeleisen, very nice solution. Is there a way to let only the first row to present the number of duplicates like in my output table example?

Comment: @mql4beginner I updated again, this time with a join query which I believe could give you the exact result you want.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Tim Biegeleisen

Comment: Please mark correct if this helped you.  Thanks :-)

Answer (score 2):

```
create table #temp
(
id int,
loginn varchar(10),
name varchar(10),
cntry varchar(40)
)

insert into #temp
select 
11, 'a@com',  'Aron', 'USA'     union all
select 12, 'a@com',  'Aron',  'Israel'  union all
select 13, 'ff@com', 'Lucci', 'Germany'


;with cte
as
(
select *,ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by loginn order by id) as rn
 from #temp
 )
 select 
 id,loginn,name,cntry,
 case 
 when rn=1 then (select count(*) from cte  t1 where t1.loginn=t2.loginn) 
 else 0 
 end as duplicate
 from
cte t2
```

**Output:**

```
id  loginn  name    cntry   duplicate
11  a@com   Aron    USA         2
12  a@com   Aron    Israel      0
13  ff@com  Lucci   Germany     1
```

Answer (score 2):

you can try windowed function to get the count and to decide when to show result.

```
SELECT
    Id
  , Login
  , Name
  , Country
  , COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY Login) as Cnt
  , CASE WHEN 1 = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Login ORDER BY Id) -- (Order by need to match query Order statement)
         THEN COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY Login) as Cnt
         ELSE NULL
    END AS Cnt_ONLY_ON_FIRST_RECORD
FROM #tt
ORDER BY 
    ID -- (Order by need to match Order in CASE condition statement)
```